# Chipmunk Physics: Draw Trajectory

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game for IPhone using cocos2d with Chipmunk Physics. I would like to draw the predicted trajectory of a bullet. Is there an easy way to do that?

Thank you

Comment: There is no way to "predict" the trajectory using physEngine. You can simulate it of course, but it will take a lot of time. So you have to predict the trajectory yourself and then draw it. Is your question about drawing or predicting ?

Comment: My question was obviously about predicting. Anyway I have used the code in this link http://www.slembcke.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1328&sid=5bd1c82d5a3742abf2a3dee59c25d639. it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is actually the link containing the code answering my own question. 
I can't see why it received a bad vote but, since the question was mine, I can say it is the answer :)

http://www.slembcke.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1328&sid=5bd1c82d5a3742abf2a3dee59c25d639